# Parsing through data with variable values

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm running into a confusing issue with a current project. Basically, I am analyzing a MIDI file byte by byte (yes, I have to do it this way). MIDI files are structured such that the data for any given event in a track is conveyed via a series of bytes called a 'message'. A MIDI device knows what type of message based on a status code, which is 1-3 bytes within the 'message' that have specific IDs for specific functions.

I need to be able to look through a MIDI file's data and record each 'message' as a self-contained object so that I can put them in sequence for later use. The problem I run into is that as I progress through the data, I need an efficient way to read each status code and match it with the function I've written that processes the data for that type of message. What I'm trying to do now is this:

First, at any given point in the overall MIDI file, I look at the next 3 bytes and compare them with my list of all of the possible 3 byte MIDI status codes. Here's my first problem. For all 3 byte status code (which is equivalent to *6 hexadecimal digits*, which is the encoding that is often used in MIDI editing), the *5th-8th bits* (aka the second hexadecimal digit) specifies the MIDI channel that the current message affects, which is variable and unpredictable. Since I can't predict the channel, I need to treat it as a wild card value. In other words, I need to somehow be able to take the 6 digits and ignore the 2nd when I reference it against my list of codes. I don't think I explained that well, so here's an example:

6 hex-digit code inside the file: `Bn7800` where `n` is the channel number

List of 6 digit codes: `['Bn7800','Bn7900','FF2001','FF2F00',...]`

I need to search through that list for the correct code while ignoring the 2nd digit since I have no way of telling what it is ahead of time.

My other issue is that once I have that code, I need to call the specific function that I've written that handles that particular status code. I've named all of the functions after the status code they correspond to, but the problem is, I don't know how to take the string that I find in the list above and use it to call a function. For instance:

I need: `Bn7800`
In the list, I find it! So I store it as a new variable called `stat_code = 'Bn7800'`.
But I can't then call my function in this way -> `self.stat_code(data)`
because `stat_code` isn't the name of the function I want. I want the function that's named after the **value** of `stat_code`.

I'm not sure how I can go about calling a function based on the value of a stored variable.

---

Sorry if this is confusing, I find it difficult to explain fully without trying to explain the whole MIDI file structure. Please ask me questions if something is unclear. Thanks!

---

EDIT: Here is some of the code:

```
self.event_status_codes = {'ff0002': ff_00_02,'ff01': ff_01,'ff02': ff_02,'ff03': ff03,'ff04': ff_04,'ff05': ff_05,'ff06': ff_06,'ff07': ff_07,'ff2001': ff_20_01,'ff2f00': ff_2f_00,'ff5103': ff_51_03,'ff5405': ff_54_05,'ff5804': ff_58_04,'ff5902': ff_59_02,'ff7f': ff_7f,'8n': _8n,'9n': _9n,'an': an,'bn': bn,'cn': cn,'dn': dn,'en': en,'bn7800': bn_78_00,'bn7900': bn_79_00,'bn7a': bn_7a,'bn7b00': bn_7b_00,'bn7c00': bn_7c_00,'bn7d00': bn7d00,'bn7e': bn_7e,'bn7f00': bn_7f_00,'f0': f0,'f7': f7}

    if track_data[hbc:hbc+3] in self.event_status_codes:  
        status_code = track_data[hbc:hbc+3]
        self.status_code(track_data)
```

For reference, `track_data` is the raw hexadecimal sequence that I'm parsing through and `hbc` is a simple pointer that iterates through the file one *hex digit* at a time. I posted the whole status code dictionary, but right now am mainly concerned about the 3 digit ones because they typically specify channel number. Also, it's technically a Python dictionary because I had to name each corresponding function something slightly different than the actual code to make it readable and functional, so you can ignore the values of each key in the dictionary.

Comment: Can you post code what you tried so far?

Comment: The regex expression `re.findall(r"[0-9A-F]{6}", hex_string)` should parse and return all six-character strings of `0-F`, which you can then iterate through one at a time. Would that work?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Code posted!

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Unfortunately, I don't think that would work. I need to keep all things in sequence for another part of the project later, and searching for the codes like that would leave behind the relevant data that follows each code.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure how I can go about calling a function based on the value of a stored variable.

This is doable by referring to the function by name. In your question, you imply that you're calling the function on `self`, which makes it easier: you might be able to get the attribute containing the function pointer by using the `getattr()` function, and then call it:

```
stat_code = 'B67800'
func = getattr(self, f'function_name_{stat_code}')
value = func()
# do stuff with value
```

This also works for if your function is part of any other module - just replace `self` in that example with the name of the module you'd call it from.

If you need to call a globally-defined function (not part of a module), you might need to index into `locals()` or `globals()`:

```
func = globals()[f'function_name_{stat_code}']
value = func()
```